# $q issue in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a panel that's to be shown when a condition is met.

```
<tab tabtitle="Servers ({{vm.dataServer}})" showtab="{{vm.dataServer != 0}}">
    <recommendationitem type="server"></recommendationitem>
</tab>
```

In my component `onInit` function I am doing like :

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .component("myrecommendation", {
        templateUrl: ".....",
        controllerAs: "vm",

        controller: ["$rootScope","$window","httpwrapper","$q", function($rootScope,$window,HttpWrapper,$q) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.tenant_id = '';
            vm.tenant_account_name = '';
            vm.$onInit = function() {

                vm.dataServer = 0;
                vm.dataNetwork = 0;
                vm.dataLoadBalancers = 0;

                promises = ..... //Setting promises here

                $q.all(promises).then(function() {
                    $window.localStorage.setItem('selectedServers',JSON.stringify(arr));
                    vm.loading = false;

                    var servers = [];
                if($window.localStorage.selectedServers !== undefined)
                    servers = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.selectedServers);

                vm.dataServer = servers.length;

                 ....
                 ....
}
vm.otherFunction = function(){
     ....
     ....
}
return vm;
```

Inside `$q` though `vm.dataServer` is set to `non-zero value` but I guess it is not reflected.

Why ?

**UPDATE**

It works when I do not use promises `which I need to use as part of requirement`.

```
vm.$onInit = function() {

                // var servers = [];
                // if($window.localStorage.selectedServers !== undefined)
                //     servers = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.selectedServers);
              // vm.dataServer = servers.length;  

                // vm.editName = false;
```

**UPDATE 2**

Interestingly when I do not declare the variables

```
            vm.$onInit = function() {

                //vm.dataServer = 0;
                //vm.dataNetwork = 0;
                //vm.dataLoadBalancers = 0;
```

It shows the tab but it does not show the count i.e. `Server ()` in the tab header where `vm.dataServer` needs to be printed. I guess it becomes undefined here. Why so ?

Comment: @trevor How does it affect? The code block is executed and vm.dataServer is set to not zero value. But That's not reflected in UI . It is still holding the initialized value of 0 .

Comment: In my view, it is not a problem of promise but the way you are using VM. By looking at your code it seems recommendationitem  is the component and oninit is defined for that component. If this is the case you will be not able to access it in parent elemtne (tab) .It will be more helpful, If you can put a minimal,working code.

Comment: @Knitesh The code works when promises are not part of the $onInit function. I might be missing something very basic.

Comment: How about `ng-if="vm.dataserver"`?

Comment: $q.all takes an array of promises, in $q.all(promises) is *promises* an array?  Are you getting into the *.then* of your $q.all?

Comment: @Spencer yes it is . Just I have not jotted down the code here .

Comment: We'd like to see enough code that we can reproduce the error. Please read [mcve] for more information about how to do that.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.